# Does Thunderbird allow me to only display select messages as HTML?

Tags: thunderbird, phishing

Thunderbird has three options to display messages (found under `View` → `Message Body As`)

- Original HTML
- Simple HTML
- Plain Text

Does it give me the option to default to Plain Text, and upgrade to HTML-View on message (or senders) that I trust?